# Bigquery input delay when typing when query length is past 300 lines

Tags: google-bigquery

Google BigQuery recently deprecated their legacy UI in favor of their new UI. While the new UI is cleaner looking, has a linter, and has better autocomplete, I had avoided using it because the performance when typing crashes when queries are longer than around 300 lines. For example, if I paste in a query it will take ~30 seconds for the linter to run during which time I cannot do anything. Then if I try to type anything new in, there will be an input delay of a few seconds. This issue did not occur in the old UI so I believe it stems from the linter.

Has anyone else run into this issue. Currently developing within Bigquery is a miserable developer experience and I cannot do my work.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a file with the query you are trying to use? I couldn't replicate your scenario. Also, I think this issue should be reported in Issue Tracker, due it is related with the Bigquery Product https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list

Comment: I added a feature request to make the linter optional - vote for it, or add any additional details you might have https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150721188

Comment: @ebeltran All my data/work is for me company so I unfortunately can't share it : (

Answer (score 1):

We're taking a look at this issue. In the meantime, as a workaround you can append a URL query parameter to disable it, like this:

> `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?e=BigqueryDisableAutocompleteLaunch::BigqueryDisableAutocompleteEnabled&ad=true`

-Michael (PM for BigQuery)

---

Issue tracker to subscribe and follow the progress on this issue:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150721188

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery works far far better for me in Chrome in comparison to Firefox.